# Django ORM. How to exclude old data?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-orm, django-2.0

I want to exclude unnessery old records from my queryset.

I tried use annotate(Max('pc_users__created')), but this is not what i want. I think i should use 'group by' or something like that, but I can not understand how.

Here's my [models.py](https://pastebin.com/76RUBxkq)

```
class Room(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    room_number = models.SmallIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Room №{self.room_number}'


class UserProfiles(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'


class Pc(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ram = models.SmallIntegerField()
    cpu = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    gpu = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title}'


class PcUsers(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    pc = models.ForeignKey(Pc, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='pc_users')
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfiles, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.pc}: {self.user}'


class PcRooms(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    pc = models.ForeignKey(Pc, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='pc_rooms')
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.pc}: {self.room}'
```

and [views.py](https://pastebin.com/rf8vy1ey):
from myapp.models import Pc

```
def report(request):
    data = Pc.objects.values(
        'id',
        'title',
        'pc_users__user__name',
        'pc_rooms__room__room_number'
    )
    return render(request, 'report.html', {'data': data})
```

Also here is my [data](https://pastebin.com/EEBMJ0LK) from admin site

I want exclude all repetitive records and keep all newest records.
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqmiu.jpg)

```
+-------+------------+---------+---------+
| ID Pc |  Pc Title  | Pc User | Pc Room |
+-------+------------+---------+---------+
|     1 | Laptop     | User1   |     201 |--> Keep this
|     1 | Laptop     | User1   |     999 |
|     1 | Laptop     | Admin   |     201 |
|     1 | Laptop     | Admin   |     999 |
|     2 | PC1        | User1   |     201 |--> Keep this
|     2 | PC1        | User1   |     202 |
|     2 | PC1        | User2   |     201 |
|     2 | PC1        | User2   |     202 |
|     3 | PC2        | User2   |     202 |--> Keep this
|     3 | PC2        | User2   |     203 |
|     3 | PC2        | User3   |     202 |
|     3 | PC2        | User3   |     203 |
|     4 | PC3        | User3   |     203 |--> Keep this
|     4 | PC3        | User3   |     201 |
|     4 | PC3        | User1   |     203 |
|     4 | PC3        | User1   |     201 |
|     5 | Server     | Admin   |     999 |--> Keep this
|     6 | new laptop | None    |     301 |--> Keep this
+-------+------------+---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `distinct()` to exclude repetitions and `order_by` using the `created` field to keep the most recent records

Comment: i've tried, but distinct will work only on one model, there are 3 models in one queryset (Pc, PcUsers and PcRooms) or i should use distinct('pc_id_field')?

Comment: yes, you can use `distinct` for foreign fields, take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct

Comment: Thank you so much!! I should note about ordering, order_by and distinct methods, should include same fields like: order_by('id', 'pc_users__created').distinct('id')